# sort Pandas Dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc7yx.png)

In my data set in `height` column value increases then after starts to decrease. I want to sort data only up to increase height. I don't want data after height decrease.

Comment: Please show some examples of the data and the expected output

Comment: Please include code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by finding the index of the max value of the `height` column, and then using `iloc` to reassign the dataframe only including the rows up to this index:

```
x = df.idmax()['height']
df = df.iloc[:x+1]
```

Comment: ypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [26144.87] of <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: @AMi It looks like you are pulling the max *value* instead of its *index*. Please include the code you used and the structure of your dataframe in the question.

Comment: @AMi good stuff. If this answer solved your problem, you might want to consider marking it as accepted (the tick on the left hand side).